# cannot convert 'filtro*' to 'FILTRO*{aka fil*}' in assigment (C)

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, punteros, dev-c++

la cosa esta en que tengo ciertas Estructuras de Datos creadas en una librería, y aunque las funciones para añadir al final de la lista son iguales cambiando los nombres para las diferentes ED es solo con una en concreto (FILTRO) con la que me salta el error. Esto me pasa cuando intento sobrescribir un filtro para que se convierta en otro (Mas detalladamente, la función problemática me da dos fallos:

```
cannot convert 'filtro*' to 'FILTRO*{aka fil*}' in assigment
```

y

```
cannot convert 'FILTRO*{aka fil*}' to 'filtro*' in assigment)
```

ED que me causa los problemas:

```
typedef struct fil {
    COLUMNA * pCol;         //puntero a la columna
    OPERANDO operador;      //operación a realizar
    char *valor;            //valor a aplicar
    struct filtro *next;    //puntero al siguiente filtro
} FILTRO;
```

ED con funciones identicas pero que no me causa problemas:

```
typedef struct etiq {
    char *etiqueta;             //nombre de la etiqueta (texto)
    int cuenta;                 //veces que la etiqueta se repite
    struct etiq * siguiente;    //puntero siguiente etiqueta
} ETIQUETA;
```

La funcion que hace que salte el error:

```
void insertarFinalFil(FILTROS* filtros, COLUMNA* col, char operador[], char *valor){
    FILTRO* filtro = generaFiltro(col, operador, valor);
    if(filtros->p == NULL){
        filtros->p = filtro;
    }else{
        FILTRO* puntero = filtros->p;
        while(puntero->next){
            puntero = puntero->next;
        }
        puntero->next = filtro;
    }
}
```

Funcion similar que funciona sí que compila:

```
void insertarFinalEtiq(COLUMNA* columna, char *nombre){
    ETIQUETA* etiq = crearEtiqueta(nombre);
    if(columna->lista == NULL){
        columna->lista = etiq;
    }else{
        ETIQUETA* puntero = columna->lista;
        while(puntero->siguiente){
            puntero = puntero->siguiente;
        }
        puntero->siguiente = etiq;
    }
}
```

Comment: La cosa esta en que antes de meter las funciones de las ED y las propias ED en librerias no me saltaba ningun fallo

Comment: Pon atención en el puntero `next` de `struct fil`, no debería ser de tipo `struct fil *` en vez de `struct filtro *`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef struct fil {
    COLUMNA * pCol;         //puntero a la columna
    OPERANDO operador;      //operación a realizar
    char *valor;            //valor a aplicar
    struct filtro *next;    //puntero al siguiente filtro
    //     ~~~~~~ ERROR
} FILTRO;
```

Corregido sería:

```
typedef struct fil {
    COLUMNA * pCol;         //puntero a la columna
    OPERANDO operador;      //operación a realizar
    char *valor;            //valor a aplicar
    struct fil *next;       //puntero al siguiente filtro
} FILTRO;
```

> La cosa esta en que antes de meter las funciones de las ED y las propias ED en librerias no me saltaba ningun fallo

El error se ha producido en el momento en el que has intentado usar `next` ya que es en ese momento cuando intentas hacer asignaciones entre punteros incompatibles:

```
void insertarFinalFil(FILTROS* filtros, COLUMNA* col, char operador[], char *valor){
    FILTRO* filtro = generaFiltro(col, operador, valor);
    if(filtros->p == NULL){
        filtros->p = filtro;
    }else{
        FILTRO* puntero = filtros->p;
        while(puntero->next){
            puntero = puntero->next;
        //  ~~~~~~~            ~~~~
        //  FILTRO*            struct filtro*
        }
        puntero->next = filtro;
    //           ~~~~   ~~~~~~
    // struct filtro*   FILTRO*
    }
}
```

> Funcion similar que funciona sí que compila:

Obviamente el compilador no se va a quejar allí donde el código cumple con las reglas de codificación establecidas por el estándar.

Fíjate que en esa segunda función que pones como ejemplo no usas en ningún momento la variable `next`

Comment: Muchas gracias!! No me había dado cuenta del despiste :D